# WordPress shortcode appears inside iframe?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I have a code that uses YouTube video id and puts it inside iframe.

```
function video_embed( $atts, $content = "" ) {
$video_link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true );
$video_lin1 = str_replace("youtu.be",'youtube.com',$video_link);
$video_lin2 = str_replace("youtube.com",'youtube.com/embed',$video_lin1);
$video_lin3 = str_replace("watch?v=",'',$video_lin2);
$videol = $video_lin3;
    return '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$videol.'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

}
add_shortcode( 'video_embed', 'video_embed' );
```

In template it is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[video_embed]"); ?>
```

I want to put notice on removed videos with shortcode, I would just go edit link and put inside [removed], and function for that is:

```
function removed( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    return '<div id="removed" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; left: 0px; right: 0px; background: #fff;"><p style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background: #fff; font-size: 25px; padding-top: 25%;">Removed by Admin!</p></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'removed', 'removed' );
```

But now when I do this it appears as result:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="[removed][/removed]?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

How to get a wordkaround for this thing so actually both can work?

Thanks in advance.